# fatal: could not create work tree dir <repo-name>. File exists

Tags: git

Running `git clone <repo-name>` results in `fatal: could not create work tree dir <repo-name>. File exists`.

This is unexpected.

Comment: For future reference, directed at anyone who tries to modify the question because it's not specific enough. The question is stated (and answered) in the simplest way that anyone who has this problem will look for when having this issue, if it helps more people without the guidelines then I'd rather have it without them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might have the path open somehow.

**Make sure** you don't have any other terminals/windows open to that folder. Check your other "virtual desktops" if you have any. You may have powershell open on the folder, and then WSL-ed or remoted into another computer.

---

I just had this happen to me. I deleted the folder for a fresh pull, everything told me the folder was gone, but I had a terminal with the path open even though it didn't exist. This might be a Windows only problem.

Comment: So, I was in this folder, entered as root, moved back from the directory, it was hard to remember that my own ssh (in another user) was locking the directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with .devcontainer in VSCode, check if a container is running into docker (`docker ps -a`) and remove it (`docker stop {container_id} && docker rm {container_id}`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows 11 and this error would not go away for a repository (probably because I had removed a previous version from my local machine earlier in the day and was installing a fresh repository copy). I simply changed the name of the default folder name `dataverse` to a different name `localDv` within the clone command, and the cloning succeeded.

`git clone --config core.autocrlf=false https://github.com/kuhlaid/dataverse.git localDv`